# Laravel Installing Passport on Laravel Version 7.10.1

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-passport

Using laravel on a Windows laptop.
I'm trying to install Passport using

```
composer require laravel/passport=~4.0
```

I get the below message back form composer.

```
  Problem 1
    - The requested package laravel/cashier (locked at v11.3.0, required as ^12.0) is satisfiable by laravel/cashier[v11.3.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 2
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - laravel/passport 4.0.x-dev requires illuminate/http ~5.4 -> satisfiable by illuminate/http[5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9].
    - laravel/passport v4.0.0 requires illuminate/http ~5.4 -> satisfiable by illuminate/http[5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9].
    - laravel/passport v4.0.1 requires illuminate/http ~5.4 -> satisfiable by illuminate/http[5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9].
    - laravel/passport v4.0.2 requires illuminate/http ~5.4 -> satisfiable by illuminate/http[5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9].
    - laravel/passport v4.0.3 requires illuminate/http ~5.4 -> satisfiable by illuminate/http[5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9].
    - don't install illuminate/http 5.5.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.5.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.5.16|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.5.17|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.5.2|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.5.28|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.5.33|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.5.34|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.5.35|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.5.36|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.5.37|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.5.39|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.5.40|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.5.41|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.5.43|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.5.44|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http 5.6.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.1|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.10|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.11|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.12|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.13|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.14|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.15|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.16|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.17|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.19|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.2|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.20|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.21|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.22|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.23|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.24|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.25|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.26|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.27|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.28|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.29|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.3|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.30|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.31|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.32|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.33|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.34|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.35|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.36|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.37|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.38|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.39|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.4|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.5|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.6|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.7|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.8|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.6.9|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http 5.7.17|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http 5.7.18|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http 5.7.19|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http 5.7.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.1|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.10|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.11|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.15|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.2|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.20|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.21|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.22|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.23|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.26|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.27|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.28|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.3|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.4|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.5|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.6|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.7|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.8|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.9|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http 5.8.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.11|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.12|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.14|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.15|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.17|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.18|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.19|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.2|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.20|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.22|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.24|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.27|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.28|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.29|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.3|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.30|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.31|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.32|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.33|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.34|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.35|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.36|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.4|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.8|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.9|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http 5.4.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.4.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.4.13|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.4.17|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.4.19|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.4.27|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.4.36|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.4.9|don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v7.10.1, required as ^7.0) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v7.10.1].
    - Installation request for laravel/passport ~4.0.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/passport[4.0.x-dev, v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.2, v4.0.3].
```

I cant work out where to go from here? I've tried moving to installing the latest version of Passport using

```
composer require laravel/passport=~9.3.0
```

but get the same response.

Does anyone have any advice on how to move past this please?

After running

```
composer require laravel/passport
```

I got this message

```
  Problem 1
    - The requested package laravel/cashier (locked at v11.3.0, required as ^12.0) is satisfiable by laravel/cashier[v11.3.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
```

Comment: use composer require laravel/passport="^10.4" in laravel 8 version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try without defining the version

```
composer update
composer require laravel/passport
```

Comment: I then get this mesage:   Problem 1
    - The requested package laravel/cashier (locked at v11.3.0, required as ^12.0) is satisfiable by laravel/cashier[v11.3.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

Comment: then in composer.json go to laravel/cashier and change version manually to v11.3.0 then ```composer self-update``` and tell me if it works

Answer (score 2):

Maybe late but this worked for me

```
composer require laravel/passport:*
```

That lets composer figure out which latest version can install without conflicting.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the passport version that is compatible with Laravel version you are using.

```
   "require": {
    "laravel/passport": "^9.0",//your passport version
},
```

Then run

> composer update

Answer (score 0):

composer require laravel/passport works on the latest version of laravel.

You have to download the version according to your laravel version.

So to solve, go to Laravel docs and select the version you are currently running and then go to Passport it will show you the appropriate version of Passport to install for your version of laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for **Laravel version 7**:

```
composer require laravel/passport=~9.3.0
```